# How to know at which point of a calculation I am while using Table

Tags: output, debugging

If I use a code of this type:

```
Table[foo[i], {i, 0, 10}]
```

*Mathematica* won't output anything until it is done: is it possible to know at which point of the calculations I am, without using some slow `For` loop (in this way it would be easy to print something like `i=1`, `i=2`...)?

I want to check if everything is OK at each step.

Comment: `Table[n = i; Pause[1]; foo[i], {i, 0, 10}];
Labeled[ProgressIndicator[Dynamic[n], {0, 10}], Dynamic[n], Right]` for overkill

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way is to put a `Print` expression into your `Table` expression.

```
Table[Print["i = ", i]; foo[i], {i, 0, 10}]
```

If you only want to see the what is printed while the evaluation is running and have it automatically deleted upon completion, then use

```
Table[PrintTemporary["i = ", i]; foo[i], {i, 0, 10}]
```