# How to get the current index during a Scan iteration?

Tags: list-manipulation, iterators

Is there a special keyword to get the current index in `Scan` ?
For example, let say I have the following code :

```
Scan[Print[#] &, {2, 5, 7}]
```

It print the content of the list :

```
2
5
7
```

How to modify the code to print the current index also ?

```
1,2
2,5
3,7
```

Comment: This question has essentially the same answer as [this one](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/56161/3066). Should it be tagged as a duplicate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
MapIndexed[Print[Row[{First@#2, #1}, ","]] &, {2, 5, 7}];
```

> ```
> 1,2
> 2,5
> 3,7
> ```

Or simpler:

```
MapIndexed[Print[First@#2, ",", #1] &, {2, 5, 7}]
```

> ```
> 1,2
> 2,5
> 3,7
> ```

Answer (score 8):

A scan operation doesn't really have an index, but you can get the effect you want by introducing a counter.

```
Module[{i = 0}, Scan[(i++; Print[i, ", ", #]) &, {2, 5, 7}]]
```

[image: output]

You might also consider using `Do`, which does have an index.

```
With[{data = {2, 5, 7}}, 
  Do[Print[i, ", ", data[[i]]], {i, Length @ data}]]
```